# Visual Studio 2010: Stop "Add Deployable Dependencies"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I turned on "**Add Deployable Dependencies**" and decided not to use this. How do I **stop the build** from adding all the deployable dependencies?

Comment: Have you tried turning off `Add Deployable Dependencies`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

To disable Add Deployable Dependencies in Visual Studio, delete the project web deploy .xml file in the root of the project. It is not in the project, so navigate to the folder.